# Android javax.annotation.processing Package missing

Tags: android, annotations, annotation-processing

I would like to do some annotation processing based on the example in the following link: http://www.zdnetasia.com/writing-and-processing-custom-annotations-part-3-39362483.htm.

However, I would like to implement this in my Android project, and it seems I cannot use the package with the android platform. Do I need to add an external jar or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `javax.annotation.processing` package is not included in Android, but the Android VM team describes how to include extra `javax` packages [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120414114022/http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages) - it might be applicable to your question.

Comment: Cannot see the linked solution. That's why we should quote/copy/refer instead of plain linking

Comment: Updated the link for reference. For the record, the linked guide uses an old version of Android (with Ant build scripts); you'd want the gradle solutions in the other answers.

Answer (score 23):

The javax.annotation.processing package is not included in Android. You don't need to include this inside your compiled app module. You just need this dependency for your compiler/processor module during build time. Therefore, inside your app's `build.gradle` you should add the following after including your annotation processor:

```
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Comment: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'

Comment: `javax.annotation.processing` is not in this Glassfish dependency either. It has the right annotations, but in `javax.annotation` package.

Answer (score 18):

There is a much easier way if you use Android Studio / Gradle.

I found the following looking through the answers of the question [How do I add javax.annotation.Generated to Java SE 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403917/how-do-i-add-javax-annotation-generated-to-java-se-5):

*For a Gradle build the dependency should be*

`compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`

Answer (score 9):

```
implementation 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'
```

Add these two dependencies in your `build.gradle` file, this will work.

Answer (score 3):

compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Simply adding compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2' should do the trick.

see here for all available versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api

Answer (score 2):

for **kotlin DSL** you need to use `compileOnly("org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28")`

for **groovy DSL** you need to use `compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue.
So generally we will face this issue when our jdk version will be 8+ .
So for jdk8+ you just need to add below dependency in your build.gradle(:app) file.

```
compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'
```

It will work like a charm. Please give it a try!

Comment: There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68221947/14291243) with same solution for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
 `compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 }`

Answer (score -4):

I find a method in butterknife. Add this in `build.gradle`:

```
compile files(org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current().getJre().homeDir.getAbsolutePath()+'/lib/rt.jar')
```

Comment: This is evil. This way you are adding the entire jre as dependency