# Android javax.annotation.processing package missing. Can't use AbstractProcessor

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations

For some reason  `javax.annotation.processing` package is missing.
I found  [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650808/android-javax-annotation-processing-package-missing) about the same issue, but it gives broken link as answer. Have tried some stuff that google suggest, but with no results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume that you want to write annotation processor in Android Studio and have a very common project structure in this case: Android app, Java lib with `@interface` definitions and Java lib with `AbstractProcessor` subclasses.

I ran into the same problem and one thing helped:

- Completely remove your Java module from project layout.
- Make sure that only your code survives, delete all (or maybe just `.iml` file would suffice?) other stuff in module directory.
- Add your sources again as module `Java Library`. Everything should work now.

I think that was because first I added module as Android library, then manually changed it to look like Java library (default structure for gradle java plugin). But `.iml` was from Android lib module structure anyway.

Comment: This is exactly perfect solution for the question. `Java Library` can use `javax`, I followed this solution and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given by vganin above.
My problem was that I created an Android Library Project (mistakenly) and not Java Library Project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the android library plugin and the base plugin together:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'base'
}
```

This works:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}
```