# POJOs generated by jsonschema2pojo have annotation which Android Studio doesn't understand

Tags: android, android-studio, jsonschema2pojo, java-annotations

When I generate POJOs via http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ I get something like this:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Name {
    //...
}
```

But Android Studio does not recognize `javax.annotation.Generated` and I have to remove two lines of code

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
```

and

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
```

form every POJO and this is a pain. Is there a way to suppress http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ from adding that annotation?

Comment: Did you add the dependency in your Grandle? You might want to add `javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0` if you have not done so. Check
`[this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/jsr250-api/1.0)

Comment: I've found similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650808/android-javax-annotation-processing-package-missing and https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit.

Comment: So, did you resolve your problem yet?

Comment: Lets take this out in the next release: https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/577

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Gradle, go to your build.gradle file inside your 'app/' folder, and inside dependencies {...} add:

```
compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Then rebuild the project. That should fix it.

Answer (score 6):

You can always ask Gradle to remove redundant lines before compilation (automatically for you):

```
task cleanupPojo {
    def trim = [
        '.*org.jsonschema2pojo.*',
        'import javax.annotation.Generated;'
    ]

    for(def text: trim) {
        ant.replaceregexp(match: text, replace: '', flags: 's', byline: true) {
            fileset(dir: 'src', includes: '**/*.java')
        }
    }
}
```

Above script uses Ant's task [replaceregexp](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) to remove all occurrences of texts from `trim` array.

Chapeau bas continuous integration! :-)

Comment: i did this and it worked like a charm, you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

- https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#using-jsonschema2pojo-within-your-java-project-embedded
- Java Project: Following above doc, This config doesn't include generated annotation at all.

  ```
     GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {

     @Override
     public boolean isIncludeGeneratedAnnotation() {
       return false;
     } }
  ```