# @AutoValue - "cannot find symbol class Generated" Error

Tags: java, android, annotations, auto-value

I am getting "cannot find symbol class Generated" while using the @AutoValue annotation.

```
public abstract  class Office{

public static Office create(String cityName, String companyName, String regionName) {
    return new AutoValue_Office(cityName, companyName, regionName);
}


public abstract String getCompanyName();
public abstract String getCityName();
public abstract String getRegionName();
}
```

Gradle dependency
    compile 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.0-rc1'

Also, how can add only selected properties to equals and hashcode function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a version of Android that doesn't have the annotation javax.annotations.Generated (which was added in Java 6). You could add that manually as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403917/how-do-i-add-javax-annotation-generated-to-java-se-5).

Concerning the question of excluding certain properties from equals and hashCode, there is currently no perfect way to do that. Often the desire to do this indicates a need to separate the properties that should be included into a separate class and use that in equals and hashCode. Alternatively, you could add non-final fields to the Office class and set them. For example, if regionName was not to be included, you could write something like this:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Office {
  private String regionName;

  public abstract String getCompanyName();
  public abstract String getCityName();
  public String getRegionName() {
    return regionName;
  }

  public static Office create(String cityName, String companyName, String regionName) {
    Office office = new AutoValue_Office(cityName, companyName);
    office.regionName = regionName;
    return office;
  }
}
```

The main disadvantage is that regionName is not final, so you don't get the same guarantees about access to it from other threads as you do for the other properties.