# Cannot find symbol class "Generated" for Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I just started doing dependency injection using `Dagger 2`. When I spun up my `modules`, `components` and tried to build my application, `gradle` threw the error

`Error:(4, 24) error: cannot find symbol class Generated`

I dug into it and found that the error is in one of the classes `Dagger` generates to do `DI`. The particular class that's missing was `javax.annotation.Generated` and the line throwing the error is the line that anntotates a `Dagger` generated class as `@Generated("dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor")`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529563/autovalue-cannot-find-symbol-class-generated-error) question helped in finding the solution which is to add the `javax` package as a dependency by adding the line `compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'` to my gradle build file. This led to a successful build.

My question is, why is that not added as a transitive dependency for `Dagger` or why hasn't anyone else faced this particular issue (I assume so, since I couldn't find any question here regarding this?

Comment: I had the same problem. I 'solved' it by adding:

    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

I'm not sure why this is still a problem nor whether this is the right solution.

Comment: For more info on this matter, you can read the thread here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95

Comment: @AlexFu - Great!! Do you mind posting it as an answer ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read this for more info: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95

Basically, the solution is to do what you've already done which is include the glassfish javax annotation library.

Comment: got this issue in Dagger 2.14

Comment: @AchmadNaufalSyafiq how did you fix it? I am facing same in Dagger 2.16

Answer (score 32):

TL;DR **use Dagger >= 2.1**

Alex is right, but it's better to add JSR250 dependency instead of GlassFish

```
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

or for the latest gradle plugin:

```
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Comment: still cant recognise my generated "Dagger" prefix component?. it was doing it a minute ago! lol

Comment: Why is jsr better than glassfish annotation?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky GlassFish is an application server, so the annotation library is strictly for its purposes. JSR250 is just a standard and contains only some annotations for general purpose use.

Comment: Then why are other android developers using Glassfish in their gradle builds?  Is there evidence that it is inferior and android devs should stay away from it?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky because this is just an annotation library so you can use it in any project. JSR250 is just a transitive dependency in this library, you can check it here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.annotation/3.1.1/javax.annotation-3.1.1.pom For sure you don't need javaee-api annotations in your Android project, but it's also the dependency of the GlassFish annotation library.

Comment: @tomrozb So I should use both in my gradle build?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky definitely not. Just use one in Android projects.

Comment: This solution saves my time.

Comment: Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'

Answer (score 5):

This happens if your JAVA_HOME points to JAVA version 9 or 10. Switching JAVA_HOME to Java 8 fixes the problem and you will not need that extra dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I downgraded my JVM to Java 8 and running `gradle build` was successful in my Android application using Dagger 2.

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer today is to use a version of dagger which is greater than 2.1 (because of the [fix](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95) mentioned by @tomrozb is integrated in 2.1)