# Dagger not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, dagger-2

When running my program from AS, I usually get this error:

error: cannot find symbol class DaggerActivityComponent

I've tried the remedies suggested at [Cannot find symbol class "Generated" for Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785530/cannot-find-symbol-class-generated-for-dagger-2), but the problem continues. I can get around the error by doing clean and rebuild before run. This is a pain, of course. I don't see a pattern for when the error does not occur.

I'm using Dagger version 2.0.2

In build.gradle, I've made the suggested changes: (I was unable to use SNAPSHOT-2.1 version of Dagger)

```
//Required by Dagger2
compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
// Alternate to above as
// provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION"
```

The other members on my team are not experiencing this, so I suspect it might be related to my configuration for Android Studio.

Thank you for any further ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance, I tried hitting the <Run> button a second time when this error occurred and it turns out that gets around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

there must be some error in your using of @Inject annotations.
if you have done everything correct, you can try 
'Build -> Clean Project'
and then 'Build -> Make Project'.. It works for me.

Comment: thanks. I have been doing this and it does work. I'd like to just hit <Run> though. There might be an error in the annotations, but I don't know why it would affect only me and not other team members.

Comment: there must be some error in your using of @Inject annotations.